# Reopening a closed Piped read file descriptor?

Tags: c++, linux

I have used pipes to facilitate interprocess communication. They work just fine. But in my scenario I want to close and reopen the read end of the file descriptor fd[0]. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: The question makes no sense - to what end?

Comment: Why you want to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reopen an unnamed pipe. If you really need to do this reopening magic, consider using named pipes, that can be opened and reopened as many times as you wish. But before doing it, consider whether it makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reopen a pipe between two processes after either side has closed it.